# Local notification in iOS coming without any sound

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

```
-(void)notifyMe
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Alert";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Local notification";
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.alertLaunchImage = nil;
    localNotification.userInfo = nil;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

This is the method I am calling for local notification. This is working fine with other applications. But with my working one, notification is coming but with no sound.

I guess there is some problem with app setting, but I am unable to find it out.

Comment: Have you checked the hardware/software sound mute switches on the device?

Comment: Ya, on the same device the alert is working with other apps.

Comment: Try increasing dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow value.

Comment: in place of 0.1 I had already tried with 1 and 2

Comment: How are you invoking this method? I think, that if you get the notification while the app is opened, it will not play a sound. Try setting a longer interval and send the app to background.

Comment: This method is being called when the app is in background.

Comment: I have created a new app and use this same code on a device(ios7) it worked. And the same code on same device, but on my working app the alert is coming with no sound. And more interestingly if I am running my working app in iPod having IOS 6 is also working fine.

Comment: have you off the sounds for notification for this App in Settings. check that Settings->Notifications->Your App->Sounds

Comment: Ya thanks that was the problem

Comment: Is there a way to make it have the sound on by default?

Answer (score 2):

I found your question as I had run into the same problem. Turns out it was a simple fix on my part, my code was fine all I had to do was enable push notifications for my app (which I had already done but was getting no sound or badge), and then switch `Badge App Icon` and `Sound` to `ON`.

I'm surprised there have been no other answers to this question in 6 months.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it happens in some devices while other devices work fine and both sounds and badge are ON, but when i install the app on my iPad runs iOS 7.0.3 i can't hear sounds from local notification all i get is a message without a sound. can you please elaborate more on how to solve this issue ? thanks